# Can SharePoint 2013 Search handle URLs > 2000 characters long?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search

We're getting problems when very long query strings to Search cause SharePoint to redirect to an error page, over and over (adding to the already, seemingly, too long URL), before it returns a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Is there a way to configure SharePoint to handle these long query strings, or will my workaround be to make some of the parameters shorter (a far more intrusive set of changes, in my case)?

Comment: This applies to SharePoint 2010 which I believe is still valid for 2013: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server-2010/ff919564(v=office.14)

Comment: I don't see anything regarding querystrings there.

Comment: QueryStrings are mentioned as URL parameters in this section: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server-2010/ff919564(v=office.14)#url-parameters. Additionally, the article also mentions: "The limitations in the section URL path length limitations apply to the total length of the URL path to a folder or a file in SharePoint Server 2010 but not to the length of any parameters. Also, these limitations apply only to un-encoded URLs, not to encoded URLs. There is no limit to encoded URLs in SharePoint Server 2010."
I'd recommend just encoding URL and checking.

Comment: Not entirely sure if it's applicable to search or how search parses URL's but encoding the URL might help as per the above article.

Comment: I don't see anything regarding a limit of roughly 2000 characters in a query string there.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do would be to ba a short as possible as the search and sorting have their limitation espcially when dealing with a large number of items.
There is no way to make SharePoint handle too long URL's
More about limitations :
[in this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits)

Comment: That link seems to regard SharePoint Online, and does not mention querystrings.